# How can I use multilanguage in Socialengine 4.x dropdown custom field

Tags: drop-down-menu, multilingual, socialengine

I have a site where I installed SocialEngine 4.1.2 and I want to add a custom field that has a few values in it and be displayed as a drop-down.
How can I add this custom field and be able to translate its values in different languages.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom fields for example in the profile (manage -> profile questions) then you can create as many language packs as you need under layout -> Language manager.

It will create an empty csv file in application -> languages (folders on the server) find in the english file the text of your drop down, copy it in your targeted languages and translate the right column (in excel) or the items after the ";" in a text editor/IDE

You can also find your custom field through the language administration in the backend of SE

Sam